# import tensorflow as tf error occur in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda

while importing tenserflow module in anaconda notebook I'm facing this error numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please consider [reviewing "How do i ask a good question" guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to provide more context.

With your question, it is likely you have an older version of numpy installed in Anaconda through pip. Try using anaconda [environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) and install tensorflow directly [via this guide.](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)

The commands you should run are to install the current release of CPU-only TensorFlow, recommended for beginners are:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```